# How does bash resolve commands?

Tags: command-line, bash, binary

When you execute a command using bash, the command could refer to a variety of binaries or built-in bash functions. These binaries are held in the '/usr/bin,' '/bin,' and the current directory. My question is what happens when I call a command that could refer to a binary that is in more than one of these places. What happens if there is a command called that could refer to either a binary in '/bin' or a binary in the current directory? Or what happens when there is an identically named built-in command and binary in '/bin' or '/usr/bin'. How does bash determine which binary/built-in to execute?

Answer (score 2):

The basic order is

- alias
- shell function
- shell builtin
- search the directories of the `PATH` variable *in order* (the results of this step may be cached in a hash table - see `help hash`)

So for example if there is a `cmd` in both `/bin` and in the current directory, then the one that will be executed will depend on the relative positions of `/bin` and `.` in your `PATH`. (*Note: it is generally discouraged to have `.` in the path at all, for security reasons.*)

For complete details, refer to the `COMMAND EXECUTION` section of `man bash`